# How to include less version of bootstrap in yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, yeoman

I am using yeoman as a scaffolding tool for my app and using yeoman angular generator for the same.

While scaffolding the app yeoman asks me whether I want to install SASS or not, but it doesn't give any option to include less and related grunt tasks for that.

Please help me if I am missing something here.

Here are the steps that I am following to scaffold my app.

```
    npm install -g yo

    npm install -g generator-angular

    yo angular
```

Also tell me if it is possible to install the less related tasks and files separately after using the yeoman angular generator as a scaffolding tool.

Comment: What about generator-angular-bootstrap-less ? https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-bootstrap-less ?

Answer (score 1):

First installed the grunt-contrib-less module.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev
```

Copy the less folder from *"bower_components/bootstrap"* in the *"app/styles"* folder. Than you need to update Gruntfile.

Add the following task:

```
...
less: {
    development: {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
            "app/styles/your_bootstrap.css": "app/styles/less/bootstrap.less"
        }
    }
},
...
```

You need to load the less task.

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
```

And as you can see this made a new your_bootstrap.css in your styles folder which will be linked in your index.html.